# Pod install keep installing Alamofire with a wrong version

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, alamofire

**Podfile:**

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'Netsil' do
  # Pods for Netsil

  # Upload
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/acegreen/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

  # Login
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'

  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'TwitterKit'

end
```

I keep getting:

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.2.0)
Using Bolts (1.8.4)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.18.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.18.0)
```

I want 4.0 not 4.2 ...

Comment: According to the doc (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html): `'~> 0.1' Version 0.1 and the versions up to 1.0, not including 1.0 and higher` So, in your case, it should install 4.4. So use, `'~> 4.0.1'` or `pod 'Alamofire',  '4.0'`?

Comment: Thanks @Larme I used 4.0 and got 4.0.1 installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following line from:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
```

to:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '<= 4.0'
```

And you'll get Alamofire 4.0 :) I believe with the line you currently have, you will get anything from 4.0 up to 5.0 but not including 5.0 or higher ...